# java connection string to support oracle TAF feature

Tags: java, oracle, failover

We are currently using Spring JDBC with connection pool implementation from DBCP to connect to TAF supportred ORACLE 11g2 server.

connection string used is

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST 
                     =(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **IP1**)(PORT 
                     = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP2)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA 
                     =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = **service_name**)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))))
```

When querying v$session to verify failover type ,failover method . It is showing both to none.
[image]

What should be done to set failover_type and failover_method to SELECT and BASIC respectively. 
[image]

Is there any invalid settings in connection string please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 11.2 oracle jdbc documentation says
"Transparent Application Failover (TAF) is a feature of the Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) Oracle Call Interface (OCI) driver"
your connection string is:
jdbc:oracle:thin:
So in order to enable TAF you should use the jdbc OCI driver not the thin one. I never used the jdbc OCI driver but I suppose you must install the standard native oracle client or the instant client.