# Odd Oracle connection URL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

One of our customers is trying to connect to an Oracle database with the following JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server1.domain.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server2.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=FOO)))
```

They get this error:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: NL Exception was generated
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree(AddrResolution.java:614) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:411) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:237) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301) ~[ojdbc5_11g-11.2.0.1.0.jar:11.2.0.1.0]
```

Questions:

1. I've never seen such a connection URL before. It looks more like an entry in TNSNAMES.ORA. How can I find out what this connection string means?
2. What could be causing this useless error message?

Comment: what does the tnsnames entry look like? Can you tnsping FOO?

Comment: It is the 'Oracle Net connection descriptor syntax', see table 8.3 in the [JDBC Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB)

Comment: As to the issue it looks to me like you are missing a `(` before `LOAD_BALANCE`

Comment: As said above. We're also using these connection. It does a fail over if one of these to server in ADDRESS_LIST is down. And it connects to one of these servers with the SERVICE_NAME FOO.

Comment: It should look more like this [connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194304/java-connection-string-to-support-oracle-taf-feature)

Comment: I had the same issue because I left the `//` in my connection string, i.e. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//(DESCRIPTION...` instead of `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION...`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is the 'Oracle Net connection descriptor syntax', see table 8.3 in the [JDBC Developers Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB).

The syntax is indeed the same as the syntax used in `tnsnames.ora`; this syntax is described in the [Oracle Database Net Services Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/toc.htm).

As to the specific issue, it looks to me like you have unbalanced parentheses in the descriptor, specifically:

```
(FAILOVER=ON)LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
```

Should be:

```
(FAILOVER=ON)(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)
```

(note the additional `(`.)

Answer (score 0):

I generated the following connection URL from your tnsnames entry :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.domain.com:1521/FOO
```

try to use the above connection URL.
Also do check if the listener is up and running : 
in windows : <kbd>ctrl + r</kbd>, `services.msc`, check whether service : "Oracle*TNSListener" is started.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(FAILOVER=ON)LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server1.domain.com)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server2.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=FOO)))
```